# Storing string into hashmap

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I have a method that returns the some kind of string. I want to store the **individual words** in a HashMap with their **number of occurrance**?

For eg, I have a string- "Its a sunny day today Its not gonna rain today". Now my hashmap should look like

{Its:2, a:1, sunny:1, day:1, today:2, not:1, gonna:1, rain:1}

How should I proceed?

PS: I know how to use HashMaps. My problem in this case is that I don't know how to parse through the given string and store the words with their number of occurrances.

Comment: You can use the strings as keys, but you must store the numbers as Integer objects, not `int` values.  "Autoboxing" might handle the numbers, but it's better to be explicit about it.

Comment: http://tutorialswithexamples.com/java-map-and-hashmap-tutorial-with-examples/

Comment: You might look at the Multiset in Google's Guava. It's basically a specialized map for just this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
String text = "Its a sunny day today Its not gonna rain today";
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
for( String word : text.split(" ")) {
    Integer i = map.get(word);
    if( i == null ) {
        map.put(word, 1);
    } else {
        map.put(word, i+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 This is the standard approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is a variation using an anonymous class to handle value initializion:

```
// customized version of Map that doesn't return null from get()
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer get(Object key) {
        return containsKey(key) ? super.get(key) : 0;
    }
};
String s = "Its a sunny day today Its not gonna rain today";
for (String word : s.split(" "))
    map.put(word, map.get(word) + 1); // use is simple
```

Output:

```
{not=1, Its=2, sunny=1, a=1, today=2, day=1, rain=1, gonna=1}
```

It's about the same number of lines as the standard approach, but makes using it easier by pushing the logic that handles first occurrences of words into the map.

You may want to change the case of the input to all lower case so "Its" and "its" are the "same" word.